# How do I migrate a MyBB forum to Vanilla?

Tags: forum, migration

I am running MyBB 1.6 and want to convert to vanilla forum.

There are no converters that I know of. Is there a way to do it using a middleman forum that is supported by both ? eg `mybb -> phpbb -> vanilla`?

I am also willing to do this manually if someone can point me in the direction and start me off, is it a matter of just changing SQL column names and such?

Comment: I converted to mybb to phpbb 3 to vanilla, it now works fine thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to build a script to do this if you are familiar with PHP and MySql.

Basically you need to look at the database entries for each of the forums you mentioned, and match up the column names. Then you could create a PHP script to take the info from one, and enter it in the other.

You would only need to copy over the information that relates to the posts themselves, so it should not be too hard.

Another option is a service like http://gconverter.com . They will convert your forum from one format to another for a fee. If you have a large forum, or would rather not mess with this yourself, this could be an option as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've converted my old MyBB forum to Vanilla a few weeks ago. That was done by gConverter team. Here is the exact page where you can find all information:
http://gconverter.com/mybb-to-vanilla/

Comment: Did you see that the other answer already point to the same website?

Answer (score 0):

**2015-Feb update**: the other two answers are outdated.

There is now a [Vanilla Porter addon](http://vanillaforums.org/discussion/28559/announcing-vanilla-porter-2-1), a PHP script that you drop into many other forums (phpBB, myBB etc.), and it will export the data to Vanilla 2.1 import format.

The addon is approved by the Vanilla Forum staff and it's open sourced at https://github.com/vanilla/porter/tree/master/packages